# didfinishlaunchingwithoptions launchoptions is nil

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, uiwindow

I am trying to set my onBoarding screen as my rootViewController in the app delegate but crashes for some reason, i have tried chase down the reason as to why and can't find any. Crashes on this line `let intialViewcontroller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "onBoarding")`.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
        if let barFont = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 24.0) {
            UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes =
                [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white, NSFontAttributeName:barFont]
        }

        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
        FirebaseApp.configure()

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let intialViewcontroller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "onBoarding")

        window?.rootViewController = intialViewcontroller
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
```

Logs

```
application = UIApplication 0x0000000131d07800
launchOptions = [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]?  nil 
self = App.AppDelegate  0x00000001c403ac20
storyboard (UIStoryboard)   
intialViewcontroller (UIViewController) 
barFont UIFont
```

Comment: What's the logs? Is there a message saying "unwrap nil value"?

Comment: @Larme there are the logs

Comment: First figure it out whether you have *Main* storyboard or not, if you have *Main* storyboard then check if your *onBoarding* ViewController is within that storyboard with *Storyboard ID* set to *onBoarding* . If everything is fine upto here then try to typeCast your initialViewController as *OnBoardingVC (Class which you are referring to the ViewController in Storyboard)*.
`guard let intialViewcontroller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "onBoarding") as? OnBoardingVC else { return }`

Comment: @laxmankhanal the tabBar controller is the Main.storyboard

Comment: 1. launchOptions can be nil, this should not be the problem
2. is "onBoarding" the correct identifier for the viewcontroller?

Comment: @RikeshSubedi yes its the correct one